# codeigniter replace array values in model

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have been going around in circles with a multidimensional array replace..

I need to replace numbers stored in a DB that relate to a status type.. If I did this in the view it would work but it wont seem to replace in the model?

```
    function fetch_shipments($orgID){
    $this->db->select('shipID, shipRef, shipCarrier, shipOrigin, shipDestination, shipQty, shipStatus');
    $this->db->where('orgID', $orgID);
    $query = $this->db->get('shipments');

    $result = $query->result_array();

    foreach($result as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $key == 'shipStatus' && $val == 0 ? $val = 'Current' : $val;
            $key == 'shipStatus' && $val == 1 ? $val = 'Pending' : $val;
            $key == 'shipStatus' && $val == 2 ? $val = 'Complete' : $val;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Has really left me scratching my head, I know this kind of foreach works as I use it all the time... I feel I am missing something (perhaps obvious) but I just cant put my finger on it. I even tried doing the replace at the object level before outputting an array but couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe placing a `&` before your loop variable should solve your problem, as then the reference would get updated.

So your loop would start something like this

`foreach($result as &$row) {
        foreach ($row as $key => &$val) {`

Comment: so the & allows the array to pass the value back up to the original foreach?

Comment: Yes, you can say that, when using the & operator the original variable will get updated

Comment: I'm going to add this as the answer as it fixes the actual code problem as-is

Answer (score 3):

you should save it on your `$result` variable.  not in `$val`

```
foreach($result as $k => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        $key == 'shipStatus' && $val == 0 ? $result[$k][$key] = 'Current' : $val;
        $key == 'shipStatus' && $val == 1 ? $result[$k][$key] = 'Pending' : $val;
        $key == 'shipStatus' && $val == 2 ? $result[$k][$key] = 'Complete' : $val;
    }
}

return $result;
```

Or you could remove the inner loop

```
foreach($result as $k => $row) {
    if($row['shipStatus']==0){
         $result[$k]['shipStatus'] = 'Current';
    }elseif($row['shipStatus']==1){
         $result[$k]['shipStatus'] = 'Pending';
    }else{
         $result[$k]['shipStatus'] = 'Complete';
    }
}

return $result;
```

Comment: Your solution has worked, thanks. I didn't think assigning the key at the row level would work? being a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Glad i helped.  It will work if your giving `$row` it's reference which is your `$result[$k]`

Comment: Second approach is much cleaner, great!

Comment: I have ended up using the second approach based on logic but changed it to use the Ternary operator